# Appcelerator connecto to nodejs server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, appcelerator

I have a nodejs chat server with differents events
"connection", "sendchat", "switchRoom" ...

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SERVER SETUP


var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(1214);



var admin_name = '<font color="red">*Admin*</font>';
var users;
// rooms which are currently available in chat
var rooms = ['public'];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

// when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
socket.on('adduser', function(username, password){
    getLogin(username, password, socket)
});

// when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
    insertMess(socket.username, data, socket.room);
    var nd = data.split(">");
    if(nd[0] == 'cmd')
    {
        switch(nd[1])
        {
            case 'admin-mess':
                //Return message to user
                socket.emit('updatechat', admin_name, '<font color="red">your message was sent to all rooms.</font><br>'+nd[2]);
                //broadcast message to all rooms
                for(var i=0; i<rooms.length; i++)
                {
                    socket.broadcast.to(rooms[i]).emit('updatechat', '<font color="red">'+admin_name+'</font>', '<font color="red">'+nd[2]+'</font>');
                }   
            break;
            default:
                socket.emit('updatechat', admin_name, 'you try to send a wrong command...');
            break;
        }

        return;
    }

    // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
    io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
});

socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
    console.log('--> '+socket.username+" joined the room : "+newroom);
    // leave the current room (stored in session)
    socket.leave(socket.room);

    //get userlist of the room
    users = getRoomUsers(socket.room);
    //update userlist in room
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updateusers', users);

    // join new room, received as function parameter
    socket.join(newroom);
    socket.emit('updatechat', admin_name, 'you are connected to "'+ newroom+'"');
    // sent message to OLD room
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', admin_name, socket.username+' has left this room');
    // update socket session room title
    socket.room = newroom;
    socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', admin_name, socket.username+' has joined this room');
    socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
    //socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updateuserlist', socket.clients(newroom));


    users = getRoomUsers(socket.room);
    //update userlist in room
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updateusers', users);
    //update userlist for client
    socket.emit('updateusers', users);


});

// when the user disconnects.. perform this
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    // echo globally that this client has left
    socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', admin_name, socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    socket.leave(socket.room);
    console.log('<-- '+socket.username+" has disconnected".info);
    //get userlist of the room
    users = getRoomUsers(rooms[0]);
    //update userlist for client
    socket.broadcast.emit('updateusers', users);
});

});


...
```

I need to connect my Titanium application (iOs / Android) to my server.
My questions are :

- How to create socket.io connection to my server ?
- How can I listen to socket events ?
- How can I emit events ?

Can someone have a little exemple ?

Thx a lot !

Comment: You'll need the client-side library to connect to the server. You can fetch it at your domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js and cache it locally. From there you can access global io and then connect with var socket = io.connect();

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the client-side library to connect to the server. You can fetch it at your domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js and cache it locally. From there you can access global io and then connect with:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

It may be even better to copy the library into your application and have a background service that fetches the newest version every x days/weeks.

Comment: i've tried to add the socket.io.js file into my app but it wan't compile, "can't find variable navigator" line 2057.    Here is my code :

    var io = require( "socket.io" );

    var socket = io.connect( "http://domain:1214", {
    'transports' : [ 'websocket' ],
    'reconnect' : true,
    'reconnect delay' : 100,
    'reconnect limit' : 5000,
    'max reconnection attempts' : 3
    });

    socket.on( 'connect', function(){
      Ti.API.info( "Connected" );
    });

Comment: @Zuhn is your code actually 'domain:1214' or are you putting your actual web address i.e. 'myserver.com:1214' ? If you're testing locally it should be `http://localhost:<port>`

Comment: domain represent my ip adress :) (i've got a little vps server)

(for the moment i'm loading socket.io in a webview and fireEvent on every socket events.. it's fine but not perfect yet :p !

Comment: @Zuhn were you to successfully connect to the socket.io server, with the client for appcelerator? I have been trying to do the same, but unfortunately there is no Ti client for appcelerator. I found [this](https://github.com/omorandi/tiws) and it works for 0.9 version.
I am looking for something that supports my socketio 1.x server.